# Retrieve date wise data from sql database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to compare current month data(expenses) with previous month data(expenses) which is store in database datewise. kindly some one guide me please.

I write this command for current month data but did not work for me.

Cursor

```
cursor= database.rawQuery(" 
SELECT  amount 
  FROM Groceryitems 
 WHERE Strftime('%Y-%m', 'now') 
", new String[]{});
```

Comment: Could you please change to tag from mysql to sqlite? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a date column in the table `Groceryitems` and this column you must check if it contains a date of the current month:

```
String sql = "SELECT amount FROM Groceryitems WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', datecolumn) = strftime('%Y-%m', 'now')";
cursor= database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Change `datecolumn` with the name of the date column in the table.
To get the previous month's data:

```
String sql = "SELECT amount FROM Groceryitems WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', datecolumn) = strftime('%Y-%m', 'now', '-1 month')";
cursor= database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: thnx bro.This function gives  current month values how i get previous month values